# Помогите разобраться на старте - настройки нагрузки для сценария, откуда брать и что смотреть в отчете (очень нубский вопрос)

Tags: jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование

Всем привет))
Никогда не было и вот опять. Есть задача - провести нагрузочное тестирование. При этом нет конкретной формулировки задачи, потому что никто никогда не сталкивался (в ближайшем круге коллег и сведущих в приложении). Поэтому слёзно прошу помочь разобраться))

Итак, есть веб-приложение с авторизацией и кучей сложных (под капотом) страниц. Надо нагрузить страницу, на которой просто выводится список объектов (она у нас долго грузится)
Я записала сценарий - в Only Once Controller процесс авторизации (сам логин мне нагружать не надо), в отдельном Transaction Controller - переход на нужную страницу. И все этой в одном Thread Group

***Первый** непонятный мне момент - как определить, какие запросы надо включить в сценарий.*

При переходе на нужную страницу происходит много разных запросов (гет и пост). В них нет передачи каких-то параметров между запросами, это просто подтягивание разных данных про аккаунт, некоторые настройки, которые влияют на отображение меню и страниц объектов (типа язык аккаунта, получение значений каких-то ключей, какие флаги включены и доступны опции, что-то непонятное и тд) Надо все эти запросы включить в сценарий? Или достаточно по прямой ссылке перейти на нужную страницу?
Достаточно ли мне одной пары логин-пароль?

***Второй момент*** - *настройки Thread Group, как настроить нагрузку и понять отчет*

Я так понимаю, что Number of Threads - это сколько всего сценариев запустится выполняться  (включая логин), а loop Count - сколько в каждом потоке  одновременных открытий страницы, а логин один раз за круг?
Number of Threads = 5, а loop Count = 3 - это сценарий пройдет полностью 5 раз - логин и 3 параллельных сценария открытия страницы. Так? Или как?
Но мне же нужно только определенную страницу померить - мне не нужно нагружать логин. Можно/нужно авторизацию убрать из нагрузочного сценария?
И все этой под одной парой логин-пароль. Это валидный тест будет? Открытие этой страницы будет каждый раз "как первый"?

И вот тут я вообще не могу понять - ни как эти числа подбирать, ни как понимать отчеты. Мне достаточно будет посмотреть время загрузки и процент ошибок только одного запроса - именно перехода на целевую страницу? Надо ли обращать внимание на остальные запросы, которые автоматически происходят при загрузке страницы?

**Третий момент** - *как вообще подойти к такому тестированию*

Это самые первые тесты системы. Я так понимаю - c помощью Thread group  я могу узнать предельную нагрузку (не понимаю пока как это делать только), при которой страница будет грузиться. А потом можно что-то еще померить, уже отталкиваясь от цифр предельной нагрузки - при пиковых нагрузках, например.
Как подбираются эти цифры? Что указывается в отчетах и как объяснить результат (все хорошо или не очень хорошо с загрузкой страницы)?

В общем, я в тупняке(( Объясните, пожалуйста)))

Всем лучики добра

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас тут 14 вопросов, какой ответ вы ожидаете? Книгу?

- > Надо все эти запросы включить в сценарий?

  да, но не все. только те, которые относятся к вашему приложению, внешние ресурсы (картинки с tumblr, видосы с youtube, шрифты с googleapis и т.д.) включать не нужно
- > Number of Threads = 5, а loop Count = 3 - это сценарий пройдет полностью 5 раз - логин и 3 параллельных сценария открытия страницы.

  не совсем, JMeter запустит 5 виртуальных пользователей и каждый пользователь начнет выполнять запросы ([Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)) сверху вниз. Когда все запросы закончатся пользователь начнет следующую итерацию. Таким образом каждый пользователь выполнит все запросы 3 раза (кроме тех, которые под Once Only Controller, те будут выполнены 1 раз). То, сколько пользователей будет одновременно открывать ту или иную страницу зависит от многих факторов, преимущественно от времени отклика страницы.
- > И вот тут я вообще не могу понять - ни как эти числа подбирать, ни как понимать отчеты.

  если у вас нету ни [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) ни [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) - сделайте [Stress Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-perform-stress-test-jmeter/), начните с одного пользователя и постепенно увеличивайте нагрузку. Обращать внимание на следующие графики:

  - [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime)
  - [Response Time Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime)
  - [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond)

  Скорее всего в первой фазе теста время отклика будет одинаковым, а количество транзакций в секунду будет расти пропорционально количеству пользователей. В определенный момент время отклика начнет расти и соответственно количество транзакций в секунду начнет падать. Обратите внимание на количество пользователей в тот момент времени - вот столько поддерживает ваше приложение
- > c помощью Thread group я могу узнать предельную нагрузку

  с помощью Thread Group вы задаете сколько виртуальных пользователей запустить, насколько быстро и на какое время. "цифры" зависят от типа теста, который вы выполняете. Случай со стресс тестом и то, как интерпретировать результаты описан в предыдущем пункте.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Мне очень помогло))